# Mediaelement.js '2.10.3' doesn't work on mobile (e.g. iPad)

Tags: mediaelement.js

Hi I'm trying to fix this problem but I can't.
A youtube video displayed through the mediaelementjs plugin on a wordpress site doesn't work on mobile, in particular I'm testing on iPad.
With doesn't work I mean that when I click on the poster It don't hide the poster and start play the video but it remains as it is (i.e. nothing happens).
Please help me :(

[EDIT]: I tried to upgrade the plugin but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the video streaming that was coming from YouTube.
I solved the problem by modifying the plugin and letting the default YouTube handling manage the video and the users interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you have an actionlistener(touchstart, click etc) attached to some parent element which call event.preventDefault(). this may cause default action been called on media player. I have had a similar issue recently.

Comment: Thank you very I really appreciate your attention!
Sincerely after looking into the mediaelement.js plugin I found some e.preventDefault().
However I really don't know how to fix it.
This plugin seems really hard to understand.
I also tried to contact the developer but without success.
I'm really frustrated...